# Zend input Filter in ZF3 - filtering a date

Tags: date, zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-inputfilter

I'm trying to add date Filters to my form in ZF3. So in my FooForm I implemented the InputFilterProviderInterface and down in my method  I got :

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return [
        'BarInput' => [
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 5,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Zend\Filter\Date?'
                ]
```

So for the filters I have no idea what to put for a date (I checked the documentation, but I was clueless). My dateInput is a string and I want to output a \DateTimeImmutable, for saving it correctly in my controller.

Comment: Use in your form `Zend\Element\Date`or `Zend\Element\DateSelect` which have the right filter.

Comment: I use of course the Zend\Element\Date but the $form->getData()["date"] is a String, and my doctrine orm module accepts only date as I mentionned in my entity for this particular field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the vendor file :

```
'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Zend\Filter\DatetimeFormatter',
                    'options' => [
                        'format' => 'Y-m-d',
                    ],
                ]
            ]
```

Be careful about the format because Chrome format sent is not as it displays.